# Node.js lessc not defined

Tags: windows, node.js, less

I want to server-side compiling my less files into css. I read, that it is possible via Node.js. I have installed Nodes.js (.msi file) on my computer and run Node.js, than I type into Node.js command

> lessc - help

but it gives me an error "lessc is not defined".

Could you someone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the node.js REPL which is only for executing javascript code. Instead you need to do `npm install less -g` at your command prompt and then try using `lessc` from your command prompt.

Comment: If I type npm install less -g, it gives me this message "npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell" and lessc still gives me "lessc is not defined".

Comment: You have to perform that command at your command prompt (e.g. "C:\Users\foo> " prompt), not inside the node.js REPL (e.g. "> " prompt).